# Magento 2 Community Edition Installation Issue - General error: 1025 Error on rename (errno: 13 "Permission denied")

Tags: installation, permissions

[image]

[ERROR] exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of '.\magento12#sql-29a8_39' to '.\magento12\catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value' (errno: 13 "Permission denied")' in D:\xampp\htdocs\Magento12\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0

Comment: Give Permission to vendor

Comment: can you provide more details on your setup environment ?

Comment: incorrect user rights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed the xampp with full administrator rights and disabled the antivirus. It worked for me .

Comment: I have installed xampp, how can i give full permission?